# Redirect goes blank page without redirecting to route Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I am trying to redirect to the previous page from the controller after saving data with a success message.It goes blank page and if i reload the page the session message appears. But directly its not redirecting to the previous page. I have used other redirect methods suggested but still get same issue. I have used following code:

**controller**

```php
    public function saveMachine(Request $request) { 
        $number_of_lockers = $request->number_of_lockers;
        if($number_of_lockers == '32') {
            $a_machine = A_Machine::all();
            if($a_machine->isEmpty()) {
                $this->saveFirstMachine(32, $request);
            } else {
                $this->saveNewMachine(32, $request);
            }
        } else if($number_of_lockers == '64') {
            $a_machine = B_Machine::all();
            if($a_machine->isEmpty()) {
                $this->saveFirstMachine(64, $request);
            } else {
                $this->saveNewMachine(64, $request);
            }
        } else if($number_of_lockers == '128') {
            $a_machine = C_Machine::all();
            if($a_machine->isEmpty()) {
                $this->saveFirstMachine(128, $request);
            } else {
                $this->saveNewMachine(128, $request);
            }
        }
    }

    private function saveNewMachine($number_of_lockers, $request) {
        $machine = null;
        $machine_code = '';
        $locker_start=0;
        $locker_end=0;
        if($number_of_lockers == 32) { 
            $machine = new A_Machine;
            $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-dH:i:s');
            $machine_code = 'm032'.str_replace(array('20', '-', ':'), array('', '', ''), $date);
            $last_record = $machine->all()->last();
            $last_locker_end = $last_record->locker_end;
            $locker_start = $last_locker_end + 1;
            $locker_end = $locker_start + 31;
        }
        if($number_of_lockers == 64) { 
            $machine = new B_Machine;
            $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-dH:i:s');
            $machine_code = 'm064'.str_replace(array('20', '-', ':'), array('', '', ''), $date);
            $last_record = $machine->all()->last();
            $last_locker_end = $last_record->locker_end;
            $locker_start = $last_locker_end + 1;
            $locker_end = $locker_start + 63;
        }
        if($number_of_lockers == 128) { 
            $machine = new C_Machine;
            $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-dH:i:s');
            $machine_code = 'm128'.str_replace(array('20', '-', ':'), array('', '', ''), $date);
            $last_record = $machine->all()->last();
            $last_locker_end = $last_record->locker_end;
            $locker_start = $last_locker_end + 1;
            $locker_end = $locker_start + 127;
        }

        $machine->vendor_id = $request->vendor_id;
        $machine->locker_start = $locker_start;
        $machine->locker_end = $locker_end;
        $machine->machine_code = $machine_code;
        $machine->qr_code = 'test code';
        $machine->temperature = '123';
        $machine->humidity = '123';
        $machine->fan_status = 'off';

        if($machine->save()) {
            $saved = $this->saveLocker($number_of_lockers, $machine->id);
            if($saved) {
                return redirect()->route('create_machine')->with('success','A New Machine with '.$number_of_lockers.' Lockers Added Successfully');
           }
        }
    }


    private function saveLocker($number_of_lockers, $machine_id) {
        $lockers = [];
        if($number_of_lockers == 32) {
            for ($i=0; $i < 32  ; $i++) { 
                $lockers[$i]['machine_id'] = $machine_id;
                $lockers[$i]['product_id'] = 0;
                $lockers[$i]['created_at'] = now();
                $lockers[$i]['updated_at'] = now();
            }

            return DB::table('a_machine_lockers')->insert($lockers);
        }
        if($number_of_lockers == 64) {
            for ($i=0; $i < 64  ; $i++) { 
                $lockers[$i]['machine_id'] = $machine_id;
                $lockers[$i]['product_id'] = 0;
                $lockers[$i]['created_at'] = now();
                $lockers[$i]['updated_at'] = now();
            }

            return DB::table('b_machine_lockers')->insert($lockers);
        }
        if($number_of_lockers == 128) {
            for ($i=0; $i < 128  ; $i++) { 
                $lockers[$i]['machine_id'] = $machine_id;
                $lockers[$i]['product_id'] = 0;
                $lockers[$i]['created_at'] = now();
                $lockers[$i]['updated_at'] = now();
            }

            return DB::table('c_machine_lockers')->insert($lockers);
        }
    }
```

**blade**

```php
@if(session('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-4" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <i class="fa fa-check mx-2"></i>
        {{ session('success') }}
</div>
@endif
```

**Basically the previous page route is :**

```php
Route::get('create_machine', 'AdminController@createMachine')->name('create_machine');
```

**which has the controller method:**

```php
public function createMachine() {  
        $vendors = \App\Vendor::all(); 
        return view('admin.create_machine', compact('vendors'));   
}
```

N:B: I am using multi-auth in my project.

Comment: Can you post full method of which redirect has happened

Comment: i have edited by giving full method. the method is working fine. but only its not redirecting to the previous page.

Comment: Where does it gets redirected

Comment: the form submits from this route. and after saving the form it should go back to this route.Route::get('create_machine', 'AdminController@createMachine')->name('create_machine');

Comment: but where is that page going now

Comment: it goes blank. but the url is same admin/create_machine

Comment: Maybe something is showing on console for that

Comment: how to check this

Comment: On inspect element

Comment: you have the return inside two `if` conditions, please check if both conditions are true because if they are not, you are not returning nothing

Comment: they are true and saving data to the db.. only redirecting not happening

Comment: add this line as the last of your function, after the ifs: `return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'the last condition is not true);`

Comment: added. as the ifs are true it shows the same and when i manually reload it shows the success message which i have written with redirect back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with route redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('create_machine')->with('success','The First Machine with '.$number_of_lockers.' Lockers Added Successfully');
```

In view do change the message display like:

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif

@if(session()->has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session()->get('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Also it seems you have not handled the `else case` for the save menthod. so just add that too.

Like:

```
private function saveFirstMachine($number_of_lockers, $request) {
    ...

    if($machine->save()) {
       $saved = $this->saveLocker($number_of_lockers, $machine->id);
       if($saved) {
            return redirect()->route('create_machine')->with('success','The First Machine with '.$number_of_lockers.' Lockers Added Successfully');
       }
    }

    return redirect()->route('create_machine')->with('error','There is something wrong! Please try again.');
}
```

**Edited:**

Change the `saveMachine`, add `return` like

```
public function saveMachine(Request $request) { 
        $number_of_lockers = $request->number_of_lockers;
        if($number_of_lockers == '32') {
            $a_machine = A_Machine::all();
            if($a_machine->isEmpty()) {
               return $this->saveFirstMachine(32, $request);
            } else {
               return $this->saveNewMachine(32, $request);
            }
        } else if($number_of_lockers == '64') {
            $a_machine = B_Machine::all();
            if($a_machine->isEmpty()) {
               return $this->saveFirstMachine(64, $request);
            } else {
               return $this->saveNewMachine(64, $request);
            }
        } else if($number_of_lockers == '128') {
            $a_machine = C_Machine::all();
            if($a_machine->isEmpty()) {
                return $this->saveFirstMachine(128, $request);
            } else {
                return $this->saveNewMachine(128, $request);
            }
        }

       return redirect()->route('create_machine')->with('error','There is something wrong! Please try again.');
}
```

Comment: @WahidSherief also added code to display message in view... please check.

Comment: @WahidSherief it seems you have not handled the else case for the save menthod. so just add that too. Check the solution I have updated.

Comment: first of all it saves the model in db. so the if is true. but i also followed what you said. but no luck. i think it is not logical error. i have tried almost all the way with redirecting but not working.

Comment: @WahidSherief just to verify.... if you add redirect at very begining of the function... does this work?

Comment: Also can you share the other routes... might help

Comment: pls see i have added the full version of code. yes if use redirect on the first line of saveMachine() method it redirects.

Comment: @WahidSherief actually the issue inside your main function.. it's missing `return` as your `save_machine` route is calling to  `saveMachine` controller action and return missnig from there... I have added check the `Edited` section... hopefully it helps.

Comment: solved by putting redirect method in saveMachine(). though the method looks messy but at least working. bdw thanks brother.

Comment: Awesome! @WahidSherief don't forgot to upvote and accept the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success','your message');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @if(Session::has('message'))
    @if( 'danger' == Session::get('message_type') )
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <b>ERROR!</b> {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
    @elseif( 'success' == Session::get('message_type') )
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <b>SUCCESSFUL!</b> {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
    @elseif( 'warning' == Session::get('message_type') )
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <b>ALERT!</b> {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
    @endif
@endif
```

Controller

```
public function __construct(Machine $machine)
{
    $this->machine = $machine;
}



public function store (CreateSaveMachineRequest $request) { //CreateSaveMachineRequest Request for validation 

    $machine = $this->machine->create($request->except('_token'));
    try {
        if($machine){

            return \Redirect::back()->with('message', 'machine Created successfully. ')
                            ->with('message_type', 'success');
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {

        return \Redirect::back()->with('message','machine Not Created')
                                ->with('message_type','danger')
                                ->withInput();
    }

}
```

Create blade file like alert.blade.php 
@include(alert) to all your blade files